# Does Hibernate has any logic like DB insert only if exist to avoid duplicate insert?

Tags: hibernate

In database level we can have an insert statement with exist query embedded.

example,

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID,Col1,Col2,...) 
SELECT @IDValue,@Col1Value,@Col2Value, ...
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID  
          FROM MyTable 
          WHERE ID=@IDValue) 
SELECT * FROM MyTable Where ID=@IDValue
```

Is there any way we can achieve this via Hibernate? Does Hibernate has any logic like DB insert only if exist to avoid duplicate insert?

We don't want to introduce versioning and look for a solution which does the above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually know if Hibernate per se has support for this, but what you want can, and probably should, be enforced at the database level.  Just create a unique index/constraint on the `ID` column.  The exact syntax would vary from database to database, but in MySQL could try:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD UNIQUE (ID);
```

Then inserts with a duplicate key would fail at the database level, and your Java code should be ready, possibly by catching an exception.

Comment: This may be doable but still duplicate insertion is possible in multi-threaded environment. assume 1 fetches the record and insert in 10.02 millisecond and another one fetches at 10.03 millisecond and insert the record. Anyway duplicate insertion happens at the same second...as only millisecond is differs.

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible assuming the first thread gets an exclusive write lock on the table.  I would expect each INSERT to happen atomically at separate times.

Comment: We don't get an exclusive lock as it will slow down the performance. We want the hibernate to take care of it or we need to have some logic in place to get rid of the locks

Comment: I think enforcing this at the database level is the only option here.  You can't do this at the app level because there is more than one logical app.  See if you can leave those insert locks there.

Comment: We can add a constraint at minute level or a number+1 to insert the record.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use SQLInsert annotation :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="story_count")
@SQLInsert( sql="INSERT INTO story_count(id, view_count) VALUES (?, ?)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set view_count = view_count + 1")
public class StoryCount
```

DUPLICATE KEY is for MySQL, you can modify this to use a merge

EDIT : Actually you can use a procedure in the SQLInsert, so you'll need to make one for each database

@SQLInsert(sql="call PROC_ADD_USER(:P_ID,:P_COL1,:P_COL2,:P_COL3, ...)",
        callable=true)

But i know, it's still lacking some beauty

Comment: We want to support multiple databases and this won't work as insert statement might be different between databases. we are using hibernate

Answer (score 0):

To preserve uniqueness and to avoid constraint exceptions you can do a check at DAO level, like this:

```
class MyTableDao extends SomeAbstractDao {
    Integer save(MyTable myTable) {
      Integer id = findBySomeFields(myTable);
      return id != null ? id : save(myTable);
    }
}
```

Comment: In a multi-threaded environment duplicate insertion happens and we need to avoid it